# rails7: test `assert true` has fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

test `assert true` has fail down

```
# rails test
Running 1 tests in a single process (parallelization threshold is 50)
Run options: --seed 61879

# Running:

E

Error:
ArticleTest#test_the_truth:
Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry 'email' for key 'index_users_on_uid_and_provider'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-7.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql/database_statements.rb:103:in `abandon_results!'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-7.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql/database_statements.rb:103:in `block in execute_batch'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-7.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql/database_statements.rb:101:in `each'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-7.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql/database_statements.rb:101:in `execute_batch'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-7.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:409:in `block (3 levels) in insert_fixtures_set'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-7.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:319:in `block in within_new_transaction'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-7.0.6/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `handle_interrupt'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-7.0.6/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `block in synchronize'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-7.0.6/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in `handle_interrupt'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-7.0.6/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in `synchronize'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-7.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:317:in `within_new_transaction'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-7.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:316:in `transaction'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-7.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:408:in `block (2 levels) in insert_fixtures_set'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-7.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:188:in `disable_referential_integrity'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-7.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:407:in `block in insert_fixtures_set'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-7.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql/database_statements.rb:132:in `with_multi_statements'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-7.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:406:in `insert_fixtures_set'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-7.0.6/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:630:in `block in insert'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-7.0.6/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:621:in `each'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-7.0.6/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:621:in `insert'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-7.0.6/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:607:in `read_and_insert'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-7.0.6/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:567:in `create_fixtures'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-7.0.6/lib/active_record/test_fixtures.rb:275:in `load_fixtures'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-7.0.6/lib/active_record/test_fixtures.rb:125:in `setup_fixtures'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-7.0.6/lib/active_record/test_fixtures.rb:10:in `before_setup'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-7.0.6/lib/active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown.rb:40:in `before_setup'


rails test test/models/article_test.rb:4
```

test/models/article_test.rb is

```
require "test_helper"

class ArticleTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "the truth" do
    assert true
  end
end
```

delete test, and run `rails test`, succeed

```
# rails test
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::EnvironmentMismatchError: You are attempting to modify a database that was last run in `development` environment.
You are running in `test` environment. If you are sure you want to continue, first set the environment using:

        bin/rails db:environment:set RAILS_ENV=test


Tasks: TOP => db:test:load => db:test:purge => db:check_protected_environments
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
Running 0 tests in a single process (parallelization threshold is 50)
Run options: --seed 15176

# Running:



Finished in 0.000696s, 0.0000 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.
0 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

model user is exist, but that dont has association to user. index too
why occur this error?

environment; docker, MacM1, Ruby on Rails7.0.6

### Sloved!!

Thanks kind people, it was caused by an auto-generated fixture.
Why is the fixture called when there is no test related to the user model? It was a behavior I didn't expect.

```
# Read about fixtures at https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet.html

# This model initially had no columns defined. If you add columns to the
# model remove the "{}" from the fixture names and add the columns immediately
# below each fixture, per the syntax in the comments below
#
one: {}
# column: value
#
two: {}
# column: value
```

Comment: I don't understand why you're asking about model user? Did you try the suggested command?

Comment: model user has no test ;(
I'm in trouble because the test and the error seem unrelated

Comment: By default, all fixtures are loaded at the start of any test run.

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing an error (not a failure), which is caused because you have a unique index on the email field, and that unique index is being violated by your test. When there are no tests to run, the fixtures aren't loaded, therefore you're not seeing the duplicate email error from your DB.

Based on the fact that you're getting that `EnvironmentMismatchError`, I suspect you've had your dev and test DBs confused at some point, and perhaps you have a test DB with a bunch of dev records in them which are conflicting with the fixtures being loaded during your test.

Reset your test DB: `RAILS_ENV=test rails db:reset` and try running your test again. If this problem continues then maybe you have both your test and dev environments pointing at the same DB, fix this in your `config/database.yml`